# How to get the prediction at a value that inputted from user?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm doing Polynomial Regression. I can plot it on the real value, but the problem is, I want to give an X value, for example 125, then I want to get the prediction.

How will I do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `model.predict` method.

Here's an example:

```
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(), Ridge())
model.fit(X, y)
print(model.predict([[125]]))
```

Comment: How can't I think that? Thank you bro:) I give your plus :)

Comment: Oddly enough, I wasn't actually able to find documentation on that method, just a few examples.